# FastAPI: Data rows from Postgresql Database don't map to Pydantic schema

Tags: python, postgresql, fastapi, pydantic

I'm using the FastAPI framework with Asyncio.  I have recently switched to Postgresql from MySQL and have swapped `aiomysql` for `asyncpg` accordingly.

In MySQL I could fetch this from Database and it would be cast into Pydantic schema automatically.

```
async def get_device(device_id: str) -> Device:
    query = DeviceTable.select().where(DeviceTable.c.id == device_id)
    return await db.fetch_one(query)
```

**Pydantic schema:**

```
class Device(BaseModel):
    id: str
    type: DeviceType
    created_at: datetime
    last_login_at: datetime
    is_banned: bool
    ...
```

However when using Postgres this conversion doesn't seem to happen anymore.

```
device: Device = await crud_device.get_device(body.device_id)
```

For `device.is_banned` I get the error message `{AttributeError}'Record' object has no attribute 'is_banned'`.

The device object is in this case a Record object `<databases.backends.postgres.Record object at 0x10d2c9860>` instead of Pydantic Schema.

I still can access the values like this:

`device['is_banned']`

Why would FastAPI's behaviour change only because I picked a different database? I can't find anything in the documentation about this.

**UPDATE**

Model:

```
DeviceTable = sqlalchemy.Table(
    "device",
    metadata,
    Column("id", String(36), primary_key=True),
    Column("type", Enum(DeviceType), nullable=False),
    Column(
        "created_at",
        TIMESTAMP(),
        nullable=False,
        default=func.now(),
        server_default=func.now(),
    ),
    Column("last_login_at", TIMESTAMP(), nullable=True),
    Column("expires_at", TIMESTAMP()),
    Column("account_type", Enum(AccountType), nullable=False),
    Column("strikes", Integer(), nullable=True),
    Column(
        "is_banned",
        Boolean(),
        nullable=False,
        server_default=sql.false(),
        default=sql.false(),
    ),
    Column("account_id", ForeignKey("account.id"), nullable=True, index=True),
)
```

I seem to have found a workaround. I have to cast the record explicitly into the Pydantic schema.

```
async def get_device(device_id: str) -> Device:
    query = DeviceTable.select().where(DeviceTable.c.id == device_id)
    record = await db.fetch_one(query)
    return Device(**record)
```

This is quite odd that it doesn't happen automatically. I have to change code because the underlying database has changed. The worse part is that when no record has been found, the cast will crash. Hence I have to make more repetitive changes:

```
async def get_device(device_id: str) -> Optional[Device]:
    query = DeviceTable.select().where(DeviceTable.c.id == device_id)
    record = await db.fetch_one(query)
    if record:
        return Device(**record)
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: This is caused by the underlying postgres library being used, since it returns a mapping Record object instead of a value that can be accessed directly. What is the type of your `is_banned` column? Does it work if you leave that one out, or does it error out on one of the other types?

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks for the clarification. I have posted an update with the model.

Comment: I have removed `is_banned` and it still can't make the conversation on its own.

Comment: I'm guessing there is some magic going on in the Record object of asyncpg, but I'm not familiar enough with that code to say anything useful. Does `Device.from_orm(record)` work (I don't think it will since I couldn't find anything about Record exposing properties). When you use `**` there's a bit more happening in the background Python-wise with the `record` entry.

Comment: I haven't used asyncpg in a while, but my guess is that the returned Record from the library does not expose the properties. Thus it requires to manually select the attributes to be fed into the pydantic model. Also, if I recall correctly, asyncpg.Record is not serializable to JSON with the standard JSON library. If you return the result, fastapi will do the work, but if you try to JSON.loads/dumps it gives an error. Not sure why, though